# Chat Program Threaded

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I am trying to build a small chat server/client using python. So far I think I managed to set it up but I am running into issues. I wanted to set the program up to be multithreaded to keep the server listening for connections, and to also continue to listen for data and then have the main program loop stay in the client send. Here is my code, and I am running into an issue when starting the listen function, it tells me the argument must be an iterable not socket.

```
import socket
import platform
import os
import threading

'''Define Globals'''
HOST = ""
PORT = 25000
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
BUF = 1024


def client_send():

    server_ip = input("[+] Server's IP to connect to: ")

    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((server_ip, 25000))

    data_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_listen, args=(client_socket))
    data_thread.start()

    while True:
        data = input("[%s] => " % os.getlogin())
        client.send(str.encode("[%s] => " + data % os.getlogin()))


def client_listen(client):

    while True:
        print(client.recv(BUF))


def server_loop():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(ADDR)
    server.listen(10)

    print("[+] Server started on %s" %platform.node())
    print("[+] Awaitiing connection from client..")

    while True:
        client_socket, client_addr = server.accept()
        print("[+] New Connection from %s" %client_addr[0])


def main():

   server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server_loop)

   while True:

       try:
            print("Select Operating Mode")
            print("---------------------")
            print("1. Server Mode")
            print("2. Client Mode")
            mode = int(input("Enter mode of operation: "))
            print("")
            print("")
            if mode in [1,2]:
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError
       except ValueError:
           print("Enter either (1) for Server or (2) for Client")


   if mode == 1:
        server_thread.start()
   elif mode == 2:
        client_send()



main()
```

Comment: Post the traceback of your error please

Answer (score 1):

You need to **make the arguments a tuple**.

You should supply an extra comma after the argument list as in:

```
data_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_listen, args=(client_socket,))
```

The difference can be seen when you look into the types of both:

```
>>> type((client_socket))
<class 'socket._socketobject'>
>>> type((client_socket,))
<type 'tuple'>
```